# PostgreSQL: Select unique rows where distinct values are in list

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say that I have the following table:

```sql
with data as (
select 'John' "name", 'A' "tag", 10 "count"
union all select 'John', 'B', 20
union all select 'Jane', 'A', 30
union all select 'Judith', 'A', 40
union all select 'Judith', 'B', 50
union all select 'Judith', 'C', 60
union all select 'Jason', 'D', 70
)
```

I know there are a number of distinct `tag` values, namely `(A, B, C, D)`.

**I would like to select the unique `names` that only have the tag `A`**

I can get close by doing

```sql
-- wrong!
select
  distinct("name")
from data
group by "name"
having count(distinct tag) = 1
```

however, this will include unique names that only have 1 distinct tag, regardless of what tag is it.

I am using PostgreSQL, although having more generic solutions would be great.

Comment: add a WHERE-condition

Comment: You are not filtering the TAG value anywhere so why would it restrict to `A`?

Comment: because I do _not_ want to include names that have tags other than `A`

Comment: *I would like to select the unique names that only have the tag A*  So what's wrong with `select distinct("name") from data where "tag" = 'A'`

Comment: this gives 3 names: Jane, John, Judith. But John also has tag B, and Judith has B and C. I want to exclude those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there - you already have groups with one tag, now just test if it is the tag you want:

```sql
select
  distinct("name")
from data
group by "name"
having count(distinct tag) = 1 and max(tag)='A'
```

(Note `max` could be `min` as well - SQL just doesn't have `single()` aggregate function but that's [different story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59881785/653539).)

Comment: Nice trick with `max` @Tomáš, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use *not exists* here:

```
select distinct "name" 
from data d 
where "tag" = 'A'
and not exists (
  select * from data d2 
  where d2."name" = d."name" and d2."tag" != d."tag"
);
```

Comment: thanks! how would you compare your `not exists` approach with my `not in` approach?

Comment: Not exists is almost always preferable - also note it's redundant to use *distinct* within an *in(...)*

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way of solving it:

```sql
select
  distinct("name")
from data
where "name" not in (
  -- create list of names we want to exclude
  select distinct name from data where "tag" != 'A'
)
```

But I don't know if it's the best or most efficient one.